# Generate a list of all fields in MDB by table

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have an MDB that holds settings for an application.  Sometimes we change those settings using SQL command.  Often we need to look up what table in the database holds the setting we're looking for in order to build our SQL string.  We sometimes don't know the name of the field, but can usually tell by reading through them. This is very time consuming.

I'm trying to find a way to generate a list (in excel, access, notepad, whatever that reads the MDB and returns a list of tables, and each field per table. (so that it's searchable)

Something like this:

```
Table1  |  Field1 
Table1  |  Field2 
Table1  |  Field3 
Table2  |  Field1 
Table2  |  Field2 
Table3  |  Field1 
Table3  |  Field2 
Table3  |  Field3 
Table4  |  Field1 
Table4  |  Field2 
...
```

Does anyone know of a quick way of doing this using access, excel, or even some vb.net code? (other than opening each table and copying the field names.

I'm looking to automate it in case we add fields in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, you could use an ADO `Connection` object and its `OpenSchema` method. This lets you read lots of different properties into a `Recordset` which you can then, for example, copy onto an Excel worksheet.

Details of what properties can be listed are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Use `adSchemaColumns` to list fields and the tables they come from.

In Excel, use Tools > References to set a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" and then try this code:

```
Sub show_column_info()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim i As Integer

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source='C:\Temp\Example Database.mdb';"
    .Open

    Set rs = .OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns)
End With

i = 0
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells.ClearContents

    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        i = i + 1
        .Cells(1, i).Value = fld.Name
    Next fld

    .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

    .Cells.Columns.Autofit
End With

rs.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to create a `RecordSet` as a `TableDef` already contains a `Fields` collection, and you probably want to ignore system tables.

The following (Access VBA code) prints the information to the Immediate Window; use Ctrl-G to view this (from the VB Editor) and copy and paste. Alternatively, send the data to an Access table or to Excel.

```
Sub GetTablesAndFields()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim td As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field

    Set db = CurrentDb
    For Each td In db.TableDefs
        If UCase(Left(td.Name, 4)) <> "MSYS" Then
            'ignore system tables
            'Press Ctrl-G to display the Debug (Immediate) Window
            For Each fld In td.Fields
                Debug.Print td.Name, fld.Name
            Next fld
        End If
    Next td
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Using `Debug.Print td.Name; " | "; fld.Name` generates the display suggested in the OP.

Comment: This is a better answer; I didn't know about the `TableDef.Fields` property.

Comment: @sigil Thank you. There is also the **Database Documenter**, which would produce much more detail but, initially, as a report. In Access 2010 (probably 2007 as well?) we can click Options to dramatically reduce the amount of detail it produces. I can't recall whether these Options are available in Access 2003.

Comment: I like this answer, but I'm not sure it will work for me, There's a few details I failed go give adequate importance and therefore did not mention.  The Database I'm using is Access 97 format, but I only have access to v. 2007 & 2010 (I suppose I could dig up 97, but I'm looking for less work).  I thought about upgrading the database, but I was running into problems, and I can't add any VBA in the access 97 mdb.  I like the simplicity of this answer, but I think I might have to go with @barrowc 's answer as it's excel based.  yet to try it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of the tables by iterating through `CurrentDb.TableDefs`.  Here's a way to approach it in VBA, the .NET will be similar:

```
sub goThroughTables()

dim tdf as TableDef
dim rs as DAO.Recordset
dim fld as Field
dim index as long

index=1


for each tdf in currentdb.tabledefs
 set rs=currentdb.openrecordset(tdf.name)
 for each fld in rs.Fields
   writeToExcelSheet(tdf.name,fld.name,index)
 next
next

end sub
```

where `writeToExcelSheet()` is a function that writes the table name and field name to the row in an Excel worksheet specified by `index`, which should be passed ByRef so you can change the value within `writeToExcelSheet()`.

Comment: I'm assuming this VBA would go into Access right?  That is probably obvious, but just thought I'd check.

Comment: It could go into either Access or Excel.  If you put it in Excel, instead of using `CurrentDb` you would have a variable declared as `Dim myDb as DAO.Database` and assign its value using, e.g., `set myDb=opendatabase("c:\thisFolder\myDb.accdb")`.  You would need to add a reference to the Microsoft Access Database Engine.  Let me know if you're still stuck and I can post the modified code.